# How to generate random numbers in matlab subjecting it to condition |x(i) - x(i+1)|>0.25, i = 1,...,N

Tags: matlab, optimization, random

How can I generate random numbers in matlab such that the difference between two successive number **must be greater than 0.25.**
|x(i)-x(j) |>0.25.

I'm actually solving a non-linear optimization problem using PSO. I've been able to include the range of my random number in the algorithm (random number ranges from 0.25 to 2.25) and my fitness function is working well but the spacing between the random numbers generated was most times lesser than 0.25. THIS WAS BECAUSE I DID'NT KNOW HOW TO INCLUDE THE CONSTRAINT I STATED ABOVE IN THE MATLAB FUNCTION I WROTE.

```
function  f  = current(x)
AF1=0;
theta=0:pi/200:pi;
theta0=pi/2;
u=2*pi*(cos(theta)-cos(theta0));
for n=1:length(x)
    if (x)>0.125
        AF1=AF1(n)+abs(cos(x(n).*u)+cos((2.5)*u));
f=-1*max(20*log(AF1));
    end
end
end
```

When I run this PSO code using the function I stated above, my best cost values are
1.5002      1.5007      1.5017     0.90902
The difference between each two successive value was not greater than 0.25 except for the last two values.

Comment: You write successive numbers in the post body and imply non-successive in the title with i != j.  Which is it?  What is the allowed range of the numbers?

Comment: A random number generator follow a given distribution, if the distribution change for each number generated, it is not random anymore. Or is there something that I don't understand ?

Comment: I have expatiated my question. Thank you

Comment: Following the mathematics of |x(i) - x(j)|>0.25 for i != j the sequence `0, 0.3, 0` would not be allowed, because for i=1, j=3 the difference is less than 0.25. However, your text speaks about **successive** numbers, i.e. |x(i) - x(i+1)|>0.25, in which case the mentioned sequence would be allowed. Could you please clarify?

Comment: If you want the difference between **every** two numbers (not necessarily successive) to be more than `M`, you can create a grid like so: `startVal:1.5*M:endVal`, then to this result add noise (e.g. Gaussian) with a small amplitude, and finally permute randomly `randperm`. After doing these steps, you can either test that the condition holds true, and if it doesn't just run it again and/or decrease the noise magnitude -> eventually it will succeed.

Comment: Please do not write sentences in ALL CAPS, there are more accepted ways to emphasize things, such as using `**bold**` or `_italic_`.

Comment: The summary of my question is that I need any four numbers ranging from -0.25 to 0.25 that can give me a minimum value when I put it in my fitness function. It must satisfy this condition; **the difference between values must be greater than 0.25. that is. x(2)-x(1)>0.25; x(3)-x(2)>0.25; x(4)-x(3)>0.25**. I already put the range of the number in my pso algorithm, I don't want it to appear in my function. THANK YOU

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, they were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have a confusing post and code. They do not match in any form, but I will answer the following question, which is the only thing I understand:

> How can I generate random numbers in matlab such that the difference between two successive number must be greater than 0.25

```
maxdifference=3;
mindifference=0.25;
a=cumsum(rand(1,10)*maxdifference+mindifference)
```

`a` will have numbers with bigger difference than 0.25, in uniformly distributed differences.